# Add a layer of mapping on a child class

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I am trying to write a class that works as a type of map. The children of this class have layers of mapping on top of basic functionality. Something like the below:

```
public interface MyMap<K, V> {
  public V get(K key);
}

public interface Client<K, V> {
  public V fetch(K key);
}

public class ComplexKey<T> {

  private T _key;

  public ComplexKey(T key) {
    _key = key;
  }

  T getKey() {
    return _key;
  }
}

public class BasicMyMap<K, V> implements MyMap<K, V> {

  private final Client<K, V> _client;

  public BasicMyMap(Client<K, V> client) {
    _client = client;
  }
  @Override
  public V get(K key) {
    return _client.fetch(key);
  }
}

/**
 *
 * @param <MK> mapped key
 * @param <K> key
 * @param <V> value
 */
public class ComplexKeyMyMap<MK extends ComplexKey, K, V> implements BasicMyMap<MK, V> {

  private Function<K, MK> _mapper;

  public ComplexKeyMyMap(Client<MK, V> client, Function<K, MK> mapper) {
    super(client);
    _mapper = mapper;
  }

  public V get(K rawKey) {
    return super.get(_mapper.apply(rawKey));
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  BasicMyMap<String, String> basicMyMap = new BasicMyMap<>(key -> "success");
  assert "success".equals(basicMyMap.get("testing"));

  ComplexKeyMyMap<ComplexKey, String, String> complexKeyMyMap = new ComplexKeyMyMap<>(key -> "success", (Function<Object, ComplexKey>) ComplexKey::new);
  assert "success".equals(complexKeyMyMap.get("testing"));
}
```

In addition to the key mapping, I would like to add a layer for mapping the value that is returned as well.

So question is:

1. What is the common approach to this problem? I have encountered this pattern multiple times and have not found a great solution.
2. How can I achieve this such that the users of these classes can just rely on the `MyMap` interface definition.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to achieve with these interfaces. They appear redundant.

Comment: The motivation is to have ComplexKeyMyMap still have the interface of V get(K key), but in the actual impl, key is of a different type than K

Comment: Note the API for [Map.get()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get-java.lang.Object-) accepts `Object`, bypassing the generics problem altogether.

Comment: The Client class here is read-only document store, so the Map interface doesnt quite do what I am trying to accomplish. Client can either accept something like an Integer/Long/string as a key or a Client-specific wrapped key of one of those types. Similarly, the return type is Client implementation specific. So the motivation is to handle the wrapping and unwrapping of keys and values in a layer of abstraction, so the API could be something like String get(Integer key) but the client used is something like ClientResponse get(ComplexKey key).